# Changing a coded min to a datetime in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data set which looks like this. I must mention that 263 means (0-15 min), 264 means (16-30 min), 265 means (31-45 min), and 266 is (46-60 min). I need to convert these columns to a single column as : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
LOCAL_YEAR  LOCAL_MONTH LOCAL_DAY   LOCAL_HOUR  VALUE   FLAG    STATUS  MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS
2006    4   11  0   0       R   263
2006    4   11  0   0       R   264
2006    4   11  0   0       R   265
2006    4   11  0   0       R   266
2006    4   11  1   0       R   263
2006    4   11  1   0       R   264
2006    4   11  1   0       R   265
2006    4   11  1   0       R   266
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this?

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
raw_data=pd.read_csv('Squamish_263_264_265_266.csv')


############################################## Reading rainfall and years ###################################

df=raw_data.iloc[:,[2,3,4,5,6,9]]
#print(df)

import datetime 

dmap = {263:0,264:16,265:31,266:46}
df['MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS_map'] = df['MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS'].map(dmap)
for row, v in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[row,'date'] = datetime.datetime(v['LOCAL_YEAR'],v['LOCAL_MONTH'],v['LOCAL_DAY'],v['LOCAL_HOUR'],v['MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS_map'])
```

but it gives this error:

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

and

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: value contains 263, 264, etc?

Comment: No first column is local year followed by local month, local day, local hour, and value (which are all zero). 263,264, etc are under Meas_type_element_alias

Comment: also what what do you mean by datetime object as XXX ' and VALUES'?

Comment: I mean having these separate columns ([ 'LOCAL_YEAR'],['LOCAL_HOUR'], ['LOCAL_DAY'], and [the column with 263 as coded values for 15 min, etc] --> I would like to have a single column with this format YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM:SS

Comment: I get that, it is the 'AND VALUES' that I don't get

Comment: Ignore values. I meant I need to have only two cols from the original file. That is my mistake, will delete it from the question now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map to translate the alias into a minute and the iterate to build your dates

```
dmap = {263:0,264:16,265:31,266:46}
df['ALIAS_map'] = df['MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS'].map(dmap)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
for row in df.head(50).itertuples():    
   df.loc[row[0],'date'] = datetime.datetime(int(row[1]),row[2],row[3],row[4],row[-1])
```

Comment: is this what you needed?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but the suggestion is to do precisely what my answer says!

Comment: Edited ==>  I have added the code and the errors I am getting.

Comment: I have done exactly what you said, If you look into the edited question.

Comment: almost exactly, can you include the results of print df.index?

Comment: here it is ==>    RangeIndex(start=0, stop=393977, step=1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176291/discussion-between-sina-shabani-and-yuca).